# longtable overwrites page number

Tags: tables, longtable

In my thesis I need to display a lot of long tables for which I use the longtable environment. Most of the time it works perfectly, but sometimes for some reason it doesn't split the table and the table goes well over bottom margin of the page covering a good part of the footer (sometimes even overwriting the page number).

I tried to construct a minimal working example but didn't really succeed. The best I could do was this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

Minimal working example.

\vskip 14.205cm

\begin{description}

\item one
\item two
\item three
\item four

\end{description}

\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{l|l|l}
\textbf{$f$-vector} & \textbf{ratio} & \textbf{generating grid point} \\ \hline
\endhead
$(8, 12, 6)$ & $1/2$ & $(0, 0, 0)$ \\
$(12, 18, 8)$ & $1/2$ & $(88/1413, 0, 0)$ \\
$(16, 24, 10)$ & $1/2$ & $(706/1413, 0, 0)$ \\
$(18, 28, 12)$ & $1/2$ & $(21/628, -21/628, 0)$ \\
$(21, 32, 13)$ & $1/2$ & $(2825/5652, -1/5652, 0)$ \\
$(24, 36, 14)$ & $1/2$ & $(1/4, -1/4, 0)$ \\
$(25, 38, 15)$ & $1/2$ & $(313/628, -1/5652, 0)$ \\
$(28, 42, 16)$ & $1/2$ & $(539/5652, -187/5652, 0)$ \\
\end{longtable}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

In principle it shows what's wrong. The table should be broken and not continue so far into the footer. That's a least what I would like to have. And as I wrote above, sometimes it even goes over the page number.

Any idea what's wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with the output here the longtable doesn't go beyond the text block into the footer at all. However you should remove the `center` environment which can not do anything useful for longtable and just adds spurious vertical space.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: That is strange since for me the table is very close to the page number 1 and page 2 is just empty.

Comment: If you remove `begin{center} ...\end{center}`, then `longtable` is correct broken between pages, otherwise you have observed problem. Use `{\centering\begin{longtable} ... \end{longtable} }` instead.

Comment: @Zarko no. `\centering` has no effect on longtable

Comment: (the english grammar was correct _before_ the edit)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks, these fine points are always a struggle for non-native speakers.

Comment: hm, I make test and with `begin{center} ... long table stuff ... \end{center}` I reproduce OP problem. Replacing it with `{\centering ... long table stuf ...}` the problem disappear.

Comment: @Zarko - `longtable` environments are automatically centered by default -- `\centering` should have no effect either way. Removing the `center` environment does matter, though.

Comment: For me it's always the same, no matter if I either add nothing, the `center` environment or use `\centering`.

Comment: @Mico, thank you for enlightening me. I test again the MWE, but instead `\vskip 14.205cm` I use `\lipsum[1-4]` from package `lispum` after `\begin{description} ...\end{description}` and the OP's problem disappear. Interestingly, If put `\lipsum` before description, the OP's problem persist ...

Comment: Does adding `\usepackage{geometry}` to the preamble help?

Comment: @cfr: In the case of my MWE it helps and it splits the table correctly. However, in general it does not help. I tried it for my thesis and there the problems still occur.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Is there a way to manually specify where longtable should split the table and continue on the next page? I'd be happy to do that given that I don't see any automated solution.

Comment: `texdoc longtable` page 9: `\pagebreak` or `\newpage` force a page break.